# Sort list of tuples according to 2 criteria in python

Tags: python, list, sorting

I want to sort this list of tuples, first by the value of the integer and then by the length of the string in each tuple but have no idea how to do it.

[(10, 'ATAGCTAT'), (4, 'TTAGCTA'), (6, 'AATTAATCGAT'), (6, 'GCTATAGC')]

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
sorted(s, key=lambda v: (v[0], len(v[1]), v[1]))
```

This uses the `key` parameter of `sorted()` to make a new tuple that has the information you want to base the sort upon, in the order of consideration.

Note that I included the actual string as the third value in the tuple, to break ties for just first value and length of string. You could remove that, if you like.

For your example, that gives

```
In [1]: s = [(10, 'ATAGCTAT'), (4, 'TTAGCTA'), (6, 'AATTAATCGAT'), (6, 'GCTATAGC')]

In [2]: sorted(s, key=lambda v: (v[0], len(v[1]), v[1]))
Out[2]: [(4, 'TTAGCTA'), (6, 'GCTATAGC'), (6, 'AATTAATCGAT'), (10, 'ATAGCTAT')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Sort with a tuple of the integer value and the length of the string items:

```
lst = [(10, 'ATAGCTAT'), (4, 'TTAGCTA'), (6, 'AATTAATCGAT'), (6, 'GCTATAGC')]
lst_sorted = sorted(lst, key=lambda x: (x[0], len(x[1])))
print(lst_sorted)
# [(4, 'TTAGCTA'), (6, 'GCTATAGC'), (6, 'AATTAATCGAT'), (10, 'ATAGCTAT')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom sort key that uses the criteria you want:

```
>>> l = [(10, 'ATAGCTAT'), (4, 'TTAGCTA'), (6, 'AATTAATCGAT'), (6, 'GCTAT
>>> sorted(l, key=lambda x: (x[0], len(x[1])))
[(4, 'TTAGCTA'), (6, 'GCTATAGC'), (6, 'AATTAATCGAT'), (10, 'ATAGCTAT')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sorted()](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#sorted) function and pass arguments to key as per your sorting criteria.

Following tutorial provides different examples of [sorted()](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#sorted) function.

https://docs.python.org/3.5/howto/sorting.html#sortinghowto

**Solution:**

```
>>> mylist = [(10, 'ATAGCTAT'), (4, 'TTAGCTA'), (6, 'AATTAATCGAT'), (6, 'GCTATAGC')]

>>> sorted(mylist, key=lambda val: (val[0], len(val[1])))
[(4, 'TTAGCTA'), (6, 'GCTATAGC'), (6, 'AATTAATCGAT'), (10, 'ATAGCTAT')]
```